# Java BitSet which allows easy Concatenation of BitSets

Tags: java, concatenation, bitset

I have a need for a BitSet which allows easy concatenation of multiple BitSets create a new BitSet. The [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) doesn't have such a method.

Is there any an implementation in some external library that any of you know which allows easy concatenation?

For example lets say I have a bitarray 11111 and another bit array 010101. I want functionality like appending. So after concatenating it would result in 11111010101.

Comment: Since a BitSet has no meaningful size or length (except the highest set bit), it is a little bit difficult to understand what you mean with concatenation.

Comment: @jarnbjo I edited the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: That's not 'concatenation'. That is left-shifting and OR-ing. I doubt you will be able to come up with a coherent definition of your version of concatenation. For example why observe the one leading zero in `010101` in your example, and ignore the infinity of other leading zeros?

Comment: @EJP I know the size of a given bit string.

Comment: @Can'tTell No you don't. Once it gets into a BitSet there are no leading zeroes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there's no way to implement this terribly efficient (performance *and* memory that is) since there's no leftshift method.

What you can do is either use the obvious `nextSetBit` for loop - slow, but memory efficient.

The presumably faster method would be to use `toLongArray` on one, copy that correctly shifted into a large enough array, create a bitset from that and or it with the other. That way you don't do any bitshifting on single bits but instead work on wordsized chunks.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
BitSet concatenate_vectors(BitSet vector_1_in, BitSet vector_2_in) {
  BitSet vector_1_in_clone = (BitSet)vector_1_in.clone();
  BitSet vector_2_in_clone = (BitSet)vector_2_in.clone();
  int n = 5;//_desired length of the first (leading) vector
  int index = -1;
  while (index < (vector_2_in_clone.length() - 1)) {
    index = vector_2_in_clone.nextSetBit((index + 1));
    vector_1_in_clone.set((index + n));
  }
  return vector_1_in_clone;
}
```

Result: 11111010101