# How to randomize the first 20 bits of a BitSet skipping the least significant bit?

Tags: java, bitset

I am trying to create a `BitSet` of 64 bits where the first 20 bits are generated randomly skipping the LSB - The LSB has to either be set to 1 or 0 depending on if the number of 1s are odd or even ([calculating](https://limbenjamin.com/articles/des-key-parity-bit-calculator.html) the parity bits).

Right now, I am able to create 64 bits where the LSB is set to 1 as the number of 1s (0) are even. What I want to achieve is to randomly set the first 20 bits (the MSB I guess).

```
BitSet temp = new BitSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() / 8; i++) {
            int msb = i * 8;
            BitSet group = temp.get(msb, msb + 8);
            temp.set(msb + 7, group.cardinality() % 2 == 0);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( int i = 0; i < temp.length();  i++ )
        {
            sb.append( temp.get( i ) == true ? 1: 0 );
        }

        System.out.println("Bitset " + sb);
```

This gives the output:

```
Bitset 0000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001
```

Where I want it to be something like:

```
xxxxxxxp xxxxxxxp xxxxxx0p 0000000p 0000000p 0000000p 0000000p 0000000p
```

Where `x` is the randomly set bit (either 0 or 1) and `p` is the parity bit.

Comment: `new Bitset()` creates a BitSet with no bits set.  I don’t see any code that sets your `x` bits.

Comment: I know, that is what I am asking for. I was thinking about having an if statement, which checks if the group of 8 bits is the third or less, then I would call Random:nextBoolean(). However, I am not how to keep track of that while keeping the right most bit as either 0 or 1 depending on if the number of 1s are even or odd.

Comment: `== true` is (always) redundant -> `temp.get(i)? '1' : '0'`

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing, what you are missing is:

```
import java.util.Random; // see javadoc!

  Random rand = new Random(/*seed to re-produce sequence*/);
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < temp.size() / 8; i++) {
        int msb = i * 8;
        // this can be done "maybe nicer", but in general -
        // set the next 7 bits (of temp up to 19th) randomly:
        for (int j = msb; j < msb + 7 && j < 20; j++) {
            temp.set(j, rand.nextBoolean());
        }

        //this should work as intended..
        BitSet group = temp.get(msb, msb + 8);
        temp.set(msb + 7, group.cardinality() % 2 == 0);
        ...
  }
```

---

You can (probably) avoid the loop (1..7) by using:

```
int randBits = rand.next(7);
```

...and with:

```
public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte)(value >>> 24),
        (byte)(value >>> 16),
        (byte)(value >>> 8),
        (byte)value};
}
```

do:

```
BitSet group = BitSet.valueOf(intToByteArray(randBits));
```

...but you would have to [mergre/concatenate the single `group`s...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10495953/592355)

Comment: sry for coming so late & ty :)

Comment: I am sure you wrote your answer right when you noticed that you could answer this question ;)