# How to join two bitsets in Java?

Tags: java, bitset

I have `BitSet1 - {2,4,6,8}` and another `BitSet2 - {10,20}`. How to combine the two Bitsets and get the final `BitSet as {2,4,6,8,10,20}`. Please help ?

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from arriving at a solution?

Comment: Use a loop? Try something? What is blocking you?

Comment: I don't know how to combine the two BitSets

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java BitSet which allows easy Concatenation of BitSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495953/java-bitset-which-allows-easy-concatenation-of-bitsets)

Comment: @xerx593 That is not a duplicate of this one, the OP doesn't want to concatenate bitsets, he wants the union of two bitsets.

Comment: probably right, @MarkRotteveel. `BitSet1.or(BitSet2);`, @Spidey

Answer (score 6):

Use [`BitSet.or(BitSet)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#or(java.util.BitSet)) to include all elements of the bit set passed as argument into the current bit set.